# Vertical align image in div in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I am trying to center align a few images vertically in a div. I am using bootstrap. The images have irregular size, hence, I am trying to vertically align them instead of resizing them. I saw many other links on stackoverflow, none helped till now. Here is my code, can somebody bail me out here?

```html
<div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: #FFFFFF">
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3"><img style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: fill; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; position: relative;" src="{{ asset('bundles/app/images/home/awards/exist.png') }}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ 'about-us.awards.exist'|trans }}" alt="" /></div>
          <div class="col-md-3"><img style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: fill; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; position: relative;" src="{{ asset('bundles/app/images/home/awards/esf.jpg') }}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ 'about-us.awards.esf'|trans }}" alt="" /></div>
          <div class="col-md-3"><img style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: fill; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; position: relative;" src="{{ asset('bundles/app/images/home/awards/eu.png') }}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ 'about-us.awards.eu'|trans }}" alt="" /></div>
          <div class="col-md-3"><img style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: fill; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; position: relative;" src="{{ asset('bundles/app/images/home/awards/bmwi.jpg') }}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ 'about-us.awards.bmwi'|trans }}" alt="" /></div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3"><img style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: fill;" src="{{ asset('bundles/app/images/home/awards/baystartup.jpg') }}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ 'about-us.awards.baystartup'|trans }}" alt="" /></div>
          <div class="col-md-3"><img style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: fill;" src="{{ asset('bundles/app/images/home/awards/grm.jpg') }}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ 'about-us.awards.grm'|trans }}" alt="" /></div>
          <div class="col-md-6"><img style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: fill;" src="{{ asset('bundles/app/images/home/awards/lmu.jpg') }}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ 'about-us.awards.lmu'|trans }}" alt="" /></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use css table or flexbox.

Comment: You would need to vertically center each image in it's own column **and** then make all the columns the same height. That's actually two separate issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the height of the biggest image per row, you can use something like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kupwhuom/1/)

```html
   <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3" style="height: 600px;"><img src="https://fakeimg.pl/400x200/" style="position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ 'about-us.awards.exist'|trans }}" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="col-md-3" style="height: 600px;"><img src="https://fakeimg.pl/400x200/" style="position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ 'about-us.awards.exist'|trans }}" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="col-md-6" style="height: 600px;"><img src="https://fakeimg.pl/800x600/" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ 'about-us.awards.exist'|trans }}" alt="" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I thing that width this should work:

```
.col-md-3 {
   position: relative;
}

img {
   position: absolute;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try simply adding the `text-center` class to the inner divs. This should center the contents of the div.

Like this

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: #FFFFFF">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-3 text-center"><img style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: fill; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; position: relative;" src="{{ asset('bundles/app/images/home/awards/exist.png') }}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ 'about-us.awards.exist'|trans }}" alt="" /></div>
         <div class="col-md-3 text-center"><img style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: fill; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; position: relative;" src="{{ asset('bundles/app/images/home/awards/esf.jpg') }}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ 'about-us.awards.esf'|trans }}" alt="" /></div>
         <div class="col-md-3 text-center"><img style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: fill; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; position: relative;" src="{{ asset('bundles/app/images/home/awards/eu.png') }}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ 'about-us.awards.eu'|trans }}" alt="" /></div>
         <div class="col-md-3 text-center"><img style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: fill; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; position: relative;" src="{{ asset('bundles/app/images/home/awards/bmwi.jpg') }}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ 'about-us.awards.bmwi'|trans }}" alt="" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 text-center"><img style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: fill;" src="{{ asset('bundles/app/images/home/awards/baystartup.jpg') }}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ 'about-us.awards.baystartup'|trans }}" alt="" />    </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 text-center"><img style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: fill;" src="{{ asset('bundles/app/images/home/awards/grm.jpg') }}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ 'about-us.awards.grm'|trans }}" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center"><img style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: fill;" src="{{ asset('bundles/app/images/home/awards/lmu.jpg') }}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ 'about-us.awards.lmu'|trans }}" alt="" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **flexbox** with media queries to keep bootstrap layout and responsiveness like this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/263/

**CSS**

```
 @media(min-width: 992px) {
  .space {
    margin: 50px auto;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row space">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">     
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250">  
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x50">  
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x100">  
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="row space">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x100">     
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x50">  
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">  
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x200">  
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```